# Need to reveal IP addresses of devices connected to a switch via EdgeMax Router 4

Tags: networking, ip

I am wondering what is the best way to reveal all IP addresses to devices that are plugged into a switch, that is then plugged into an EdgeMax Router 4 by Ubiquiti. I attempted to use the nmap command on linux to reveal all devices behind 192.168.1.1/24, which is the address that the switch is plugged into, but only some devices came back. I was searching for the IP address of an OpenBMC device connected via the switch, but I couldn't find it.

The switch is a basic TP-Link gigabit 8 port switch (SG-1008D) and to my knowledge and research, it doesn't appear to have a web console or interface to reveal IPs there. And when I log into my EdgeMax Router 4, I only see devices at the router level.

I am not the most versed in networking knowledge, but I did a few things first to research. If anyone has any further suggestions on what else I could try, please let me know.

Comment: Switches know nothing about IP addresses; they switch based on the ethernet MAC address and have a MAC address table that relates the MAC address to a switch interface. You would need a managed switch to be able to see that table. The router like all other hosts will have an ARP table that relates IP addresses to MAC addresses, but entries in an ARP table expire.

Answer (score 1):

Only layer 3 switches have the ability to display the IP address of the devices directly connected to them. Your [SG-1008D](https://static.tp-link.com/upload/manual/2022/202204/20220429/7106509633_TL-SG1005D(UN)9.0_TL-SG1008D(UN)9.0_IG.pdf) is just an unmanaged switch and it will not be able to display the MAC or the IP address of the devices connected to it. You will be able to identify the MAC and IP address of the devices connected to the switch by running network tools such as [Angry IP Scanner](https://angryip.org/) or by looking into the connected devices list of the router. But that will not show you the ports where the devices are connected to in the switch.